# Error occur with Net-info is not working in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am using Net-info in my code for checking internet connectivity  but it is not working for me.  It will give error..

**Type Error: undefined is not an object(evaluating'_reactNative.Netinfo.isConected')**

I have also set permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

but it is not working for me

and my code is here..

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, NetInfo } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{

  constructor(){

    super();

    this.state={

      connection_Status : ""

    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this._handleConnectivityChange

    );

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {

      if(isConnected == true)
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
      }
      else
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
      }

    });
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this._handleConnectivityChange

    );

  }

  _handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {

    if(isConnected == true)
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
      }
      else
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
      }
  };

  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>


        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 20}}> You are { this.state.connection_Status } </Text>


      </View>

    );

  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 20
  },

  TextStyle: {
    fontSize:20,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }

});
```

how can solve this problem please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whats version of React Native you have, but netinfo has been extracted to a different library.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo

Comment: i am using react native version 0.60

Comment: Deprecated. Use react-native-community/react-native-netinfo instead.

from react-native documentation

Answer (score 0):

you must change

```
const {
    View,
    ImageBackground,
    ActivityIndicator,
    NetInfo,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
} = ReactNative;
```

to

```
const {
    View,
    ImageBackground,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
} = ReactNative;

const NetInfo = require('@react-native-community/netinfo');
 in node-module/react-native-cached-image/CachedImage.js
```

Comment: I have no idea what the first variant is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

For people who try to use this in 2021, netinfo is separated from react native, and need to be imported separately from here :
https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo

if there are still error when using it, it is maybe because the fetch is depreciated, so no need to use

```
componentDidMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this._handleConnectivityChange

    );

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {

      if(isConnected == true)
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
      }
      else
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
      }

    });
  }
```

instead use this

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(this.handleConnectivityChange);

    // The fetch is not needed as the listen will send the current state when you subscribe to it
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.removeEventListener(this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = state => {
    if (state.isConnected) {
      Alert.alert('online');
      this.setState({connection_Status: 'Online'});
    } else {
      Alert.alert('offline');
      this.setState({connection_Status: 'Offline'});
    }
  };
```

as mentioned in this github
https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/279

Comment: The split has been [mentioned in Adrian Warkocz's 2019 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57071306).

Comment: (As a rule, do not present ineffective alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I'm using old react native "`react-native`": "0.62.2". now netinfo(`@react-native-community/netinfo`) version is `9.3.9` and this version is not working fine in my project.so, I just used

```
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.9"
```

to

```
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.2"
```

means I just downgrade the version